# Tab selection was dropped after returning to the iOS app

Tags: bug, ios-app

Steps to reproduce:

1. Select any tab on the left panel (e.g. Feed page):

   > [image: feed page]
2. Perform any of following actions:

   - Switch to another app and go back via iDevice Home button.
   - Open and close (via swipe) bottom or top menu of the iOS

Selection was dropped (anything else is preserved):

> [image: no selection]

---

- App Version: 1.6.1.2
- Device: iPad Air 2 (Wi-Fi)
- OS Version: Version 10.1.1 (Build 14B100)